# class WP Query Wordpress вывод постов

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-query

```
$query = new WP_Query('p=44');
print_r($query);
```

это код не выводит пост по id. В чем дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так сделать запрос

```
$args = array(
  'p'         => 44, 
  'post_type' => 'any'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь и сокращение потерянного времени. Все работает. Не могу понять, почему на kama описан такой нерабочий вариант

Comment: параметр post_type - обязательный? Без него по id также ничего не приходит

Comment: @Proshka можно после вызова сделать вывод запроса <?php echo (string)$query->request; ?> и посмотреть, что формируется в запросе на базу

Comment: Уже посмотрел и разобрался, спасибо